# Find last used row and then select the cell below it in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-macros

I am new to google sheets and to java.
Stuff I used to do easily in excel humbles me in Google sheets.

I am trying to find the last row used in a range and then activate a cell below it.

```
function SortCleared() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ss.getRange('A18:J218').activate()
   .sort([{column: 8, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);

var Avals = ss.getRange("A18:A218").getValues();
var ALast = Avals.filter(String).length;

Logger.log(ALast);
ss.getRange(ALast,1,0,0);
};
```

Logger is returning `2.0` for `ALast`
error I get is "**Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number)**"

Also I tried just `ss.getRange(ALast,1);` with same result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it to work with this:

```
function SortCleared() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 ss.getRange('A18:J218').activate()
   .sort([{column: 8, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
 var Avals = ss.getRange("A18:A218").getValues();
 var ALast = Avals.filter(String).length;
 var ALast= ALast +18;

 ss.setActiveRange(ss.getRange('A'+ ALast));
 };
```

A follow up question:
is there a way to add the 18 to `ALast` without the extra line?

Comment: Also why can I only seem to get this to work using `A1` notation and not `1,1` notation